Question on two types of Frobenius theorem in $p$-adic groups
Let $G$ be a $p$-adic classical group and let $P_0$ be a minimal parabolic subgroup of $G$. Let $P=MN$ be a
standard parabolic subgroup containing $P_0$. Let $\text{Ind}$ and $\text{Jac}$ be the normalized parabolic induction functor and Jacquet functor, respectively.
Then for smooth representations $\pi$ of $G$ and $\rho$ of $M$, the Frobenius reciprocity law says that
$$\text{Hom}_{G}(\pi, \text{Ind}(\rho))\simeq \text{Hom}_{M}(\text{Jac}(\pi),\rho).$$
On the other hand, if $\pi$ is unitary, then Theorem 2.29 of [Bernstein] (https://www.uni-muenster.de/imperia/md/content/theoretische_mathematik/topologie/bernstein-zelevinsky.pdf) says that
$$\text{Hom}_{G}(\text{Ind}(\rho),\pi)\simeq \text{Hom}_{M}(\delta_{P}^{-1}\cdot\rho, \text{Jac}(\pi))$$ does hold.
I am wondering why the modulus character $\delta_{P}^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ occurs in this reciprocity while it does not appear in the first reciprocity law.
Any comments will be appreciated!

A priori only the first reciprocity is to be expected, and the second is a marvellous surprise. The modulus comes in some sense from the failure of induction to preserve semisimplicity, but beyond that I think you have to get into details of the proof and of normalised vs. unnormalised induction (though it'd be great if someone could correct me with an intuitive picture). Or you've already read the proof, and are wondering about a particular detail?

@LSpice, thanks for the comment. I didn’t look the proof yet but when I see this first, it looks weird compared to the first reciprocity. Therefore, I asked here for the intuitive explanation for the appearance of modulus character in the second reciprocity.

Bushnell and Henniart The Local Langlands Conjecture for GL(2) Section 3.5 contains an exposition on it.

@LSpice, furthermore, in the Bernstein’s note, he used unnormalized induction and so $\delta_P^{-1}$ appears but in my case, I used normalized induction and so $\delta_P^{-\frac{1}{2}}$ appears in the above formula.

@Andrew You should replace the restriction $\pi_{\mid M}$ by the Jacquet functor $\pi_N$.

@PaulBroussous, Oh, sorry for late reply! I corrected the question accordingly. Thank you!
